# API to detect iOS bold text is turned on?

Tags: ios, fonts

My app pushes the limits of what can be displayed on the screen, such that turning on bold text breaks the display. I can imagine asking for the width of a character, and then using `CGAffineTransform` to slightly shrink the display. Is there a combination of iOS APIs that I can use to detect bold turned on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessibility settings are one of the things that are stored in `UITraitCollection`. So, you can detect it via this method:

```swift
if UITraitCollection.current.legibilityWeight == .bold {
    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Alternatively, if you're going to ignore the user's preferences (I don't know if smaller bolder text would be better than larger, less bold text, it depends entirely on the content you're using) you could use `setOverrideTraitCollection` from a containing view controller, copy the existing traits, but set the legibility weight to `.regular`.